# In python, how do I merge dictionary elements with similar keys?

Tags: python

In git, I run `git shortlog -sn` to build a list of authors & their commits in a repo. In some cases, multiple authors are actually the same person but with different case or first name instead of first+last. Example:

```
$ git shortlog -sn
100 John Doe
 50 john
```

Using `subprocess` in my Python script to execute this command, I eventually parse it into a dictionary. As an example, it would be like this:

```
>>> users = {"John Doe": 100, "john": 50}
>>> users
{'John Doe': 100, 'john': 50}
```

I need to loop through these and run a regex on the keys to compare whether 2 names start with the same first name (regardless of case) and:

1. Combine the keys to show the different author names
2. Sum the commits (value) of each element. So the end result should be:

   ```
   {'John Doe, john': 150}
   ```

I could probably come up with some crude implementation for this, but it wouldn't be very pythonic. Looking for a clean and simple implementation.

Comment: There is no simple way to do that. You have to decide on a set of rules for determining whether a name is the same person or not, and that sounds really hard to me (the problem is poorly constrained).

Comment: From the looks of the example it seems that `john` isn't going by the name `jon` or `Jonathan Doe` or `wolf` - I took the use of regex to be a red herring. Otherwise this is a non trivial problem but you can use the snippets below as a starting point

Comment: @wim: To be fair, my question is not about the best way to compare names. In fact I clearly stated to compare first names only. The problem I'm trying to solve is how to merge the dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a straightforward solution would be like this

```
data = {"John Doe": 100, "john": 50}
new_data = {}
for name, amount in data.items():
    first_name = name.lower().split(" ")[0]
    (current_names, current_amount) = new_data.get(first_name, [[], 0])
    current_names.append(name)
    current_amount += amount
    new_data[first_name] = [current_names, current_amount]

new_data
#=> {'john': [['john', 'John Doe'], 150]}

names_and_data = {}
for names, amount in new_data.values():
    joined_names = ", ".join(names)
    names_and_data[joined_names] = amount

names_and_data
#=> {'john, John Doe': 150}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Snippet

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for u in users:
    k = u.split()[0].lower()
    dd[k].append(u)

merged = {','.join(names): sum(users[name] for name in names)
          for firstname, names in dd.items()}
```

## Explanation

This approach uses a defaultdict to collect all the same case-independent firstnames.

```
In [184]: from collections import defaultdict

In [185]: dd = defaultdict(list)

In [186]: for u in users:
     ...:     k = u.split()[0].lower()
     ...:     dd[k].append(u)
     ...:

In [187]: dd
Out[187]: defaultdict(list, {'john': ['john', 'John Doe']})
```

You can then use this lookup table to create your merged format as follows

```
In [188]: merged = {','.join(names): sum(users[name] for name in names)
    ...:            for firstname, names in dd.items()}

In [189]: merged
Out[189]: {'john,John Doe': 150}
```

for aesthetics to get you exact result you can also add a space in the `join`

```
In [188]: merged = {', '.join(names): sum(users[name] for name in names)
    ...:            for firstname, names in dd.items()}

In [189]: merged
Out[189]: {'john, John Doe': 150}
```

Note that this will not distinguish between

```
jonathan
john
jon
jon-dawg
```

As @wim suggested this is a far more complex problem requiring some custom regex

Comment: Thanks, distinguishing between those names is a non-issue and out of scope of my question. Again as I mentioned in a reply to @wim, my question was not about how to compare and disambiguate names.